# Select parent element, THEN select next sibling

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button that selects the parent element, THEN selects the next sibling of this parent element and apply a style to it. All without ID's, so that I can iterate it unlimited.

My HTML:

```
<div>
  <h4>Vraag 1</h4>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Wat is het hoofdingrediënt van het Texelse recept?</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier uw antwoord in">
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group row col-sm-12">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Volgende vraag</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
  <h4>Vraag 1</h4>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Wat is het hoofdingrediënt van het Texelse recept?</label>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier uw antwoord in">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row col-sm-12" style="display: none;">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Volgende vraag</button>
    </div>

 </div>
```

As you can see I am creating multiple div parent containers, with a button in it which performs `myFunction()` onclick. So without using an ID i want to select the `parent div`, THEN the next sibling and change `display: none;` to `display: block;`.

My JS so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction(this) {
     var x = parentElement;
     x.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
   }
</script>
```

Is this possible with JS?

Comment: You should not name your function parameter `this`. And if you specify a function parameter in the function declaration itself, then you _call_ of that function should also actually pass a value for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you should pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function. Then you have to find the grand parent of the current element. Also, as `nextSibling` returns any kind of node, you should use [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) as this always return an element:

```js
function myFunction(el) {
  var x = el.parentElement.parentElement;
  x.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>Vraag 1</h4>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Wat is het hoofdingrediënt van het Texelse recept?</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier uw antwoord in">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row col-sm-12">
    <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Volgende vraag</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
  <h4>Vraag 1</h4>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-12 col-form-label">Wat is het hoofdingrediënt van het Texelse recept?</label>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Vul hier uw antwoord in">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row col-sm-12" style="display: none;"> 
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Volgende vraag</button>
  </div>
</div>
```